# Efficently relabel some elements from 1 to k keeping the order

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a set of n elements, and some of them are uniquely labelled, with integers from 1 to k.

An action will label an unlabelled element, with something like x-0.1, x \in [1,k], and remove some of the labels.

After this action, I want to relabel uniquely the elements, from 1 to k', i.e. filling gaps and putting everything integers.

I tried with a hashset + sorting the elements then relabeling, but it's not efficient.

I tried to keep the labels in a sorted map, and then insert with hint in a new map since it's sorted. But still, according to gprof, I spend most of my time in inserting/re-balancing the tree/memcpy...

I'm listening to any way of doing this task efficiently :)

Example :

Initially, I have elements let say:

```
v1 : no label
v2 : 4
v3 : 2
v4 : no label
v5 : 1
v6 : 3
```

After 1 action:

```
v1 : 3.9
v2 : 4
v3 : no label
v4 : no label
v5 : 1
v6 : 3
```

Goal:

```
v1 : 3
v2 : 4
v3 : no label
v4 : no label
v5 : 1
v6 : 2
```

Edit : my c++ attemp. m is a map where keys are the labels and values are the elements, Labels is a vector indiced by the elements and containing the labels.

```
int label = 1;
std::map<float, int> tmp;
for(auto it = m.begin() ; it != m.end() ; ) {
  auto nh = m.extract(it++);
  Labels[it->second] = label; 
  nh.key() = label++;
  tmp.insert(tmp.end(), std::move(nh));   //should be O(1) given the hint
}
tmp.swap(m);
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of input/output?

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please don't forget how to create a [mre], or how to [edit] your questions.

Comment: The step from "after 1 action" to "goal" seems of linear complexity when  the stuff is sorted by label ... so it is unclear what inserting, rebalancing and memcpy you are doing there.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I added my code sample. I can add the gprof extract, not sure it helps.

Comment: Why you extract from m at all if your'e going to throw it away anyway? And how std::vector of float and int pairs sorted by floats was even less efficient?

Comment: @ÖöTiib maybe i used too fast this solution I will investigate https://stackoverflow.com/a/38164373/6225525

Comment: While often not necessary, I think in this special case it would help if you gave to us the name of the algorithm you try to implement (or the use case of all that). As it is, I have a hard time to think about the problem, because I do not see the implications.

Comment: @BitTickler sure, it's a simulated annealing, where each action is some local move of a local search. I have to relabel s.t. the next move makes sense. It's a bit annoying that most of the time of the algorithm is spent on this minor task...

Comment: Are you sure about the goal labels for V1 and V6? I have a solution, using a `std::priority_queue<T>`, which might be it but I get as output `v1-> 2, v6->3`...

Comment: yes, since label(v1) = 3.9 > label(v6) = 3

Answer (score 0):

While this is probably (almost certainly) not the exact solution to your problem, I think it could be on the right track and be bent into shape according to your needs.

When `label()`-ing a previously unlabeled item, it picks the lowest **available** unique label.

And when `unlabel()`-ing a previously labeled item, it puts that label back into the priority queue of `freeLabels`.

As such, the only sorting operations taking place are within the priority queue, while the order of elements and labels remains constant.

But, this solution does not yield exactly your desired "goal" output. V1 and V6 labels are switched... You decide if this helps or not ;)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

using Label_t = uint32_t; // or size_t if you need more or something shorter - whatever

using Element_t = int32_t; // or however your elements look like

using ElementVector = std::vector<Element_t>;
using LabelVector = std::vector<Label_t>;
using FreeLabels = std::priority_queue<Label_t, std::vector<Label_t>, std::greater<Label_t>>;

constexpr Label_t NO_LABEL = UINT32_C(0);

struct Problem {
  ElementVector elements;
  LabelVector labels;
  FreeLabels freeLabels;
};

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,
             const typename std::vector<T>& data) {
  switch( data.size()) {
  case 0:
    os << "{}";
    break;
  default: {
    os << "{" << data[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
      os << ", " << data[i];
    }
    os << "}";
  } break;
  }
  return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,
             FreeLabels pq) {
  if (pq.empty()) {
    os << "{}";
  } else {
    bool first = true;
    while(!pq.empty()) {
      if (first) {
    os << "{" << pq.top();
    first = false;
      } else 
    os << ", " << pq.top();
      pq.pop();
    }
    os << "}";
  }
  return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,
             const Problem& problem) {
  os << "Problem: { " << std::endl
     << "  elements: " << problem.elements << "," << std::endl
     << "  labels: " << problem.labels << "," << std::endl
     << "  freeLabels: " << problem.freeLabels << std::endl
     << "}" << std::endl;
  return os;
}

  

void createSampleProblem(Problem& problem) {
  constexpr size_t n_values = 6;
  problem.elements.clear();
  problem.elements.resize(n_values);
  problem.labels.clear();
  problem.labels.resize(n_values, NO_LABEL);
  ElementVector presets{{-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6}};
  std::copy(presets.cbegin(), presets.cend(),
        problem.elements.begin());
  // priority queue should have a `clear()` method but it doesn't.
  // problem.freeLabels.c.clear(); also not working because reasons...
  while (!problem.freeLabels.empty()) {
    problem.freeLabels.pop();
  }
  for (Label_t label = UINT32_C(1); label <= n_values; label++) {
    problem.freeLabels.push(label);
  }

  assert(UINT32_C(1) == problem.freeLabels.top());

  problem.labels[4] = problem.freeLabels.top();
  problem.freeLabels.pop();
  problem.labels[2] = problem.freeLabels.top();
  problem.freeLabels.pop();
  problem.labels[5] = problem.freeLabels.top();
  problem.freeLabels.pop();
  problem.labels[1] = problem.freeLabels.top();
  problem.freeLabels.pop();
}

// assigns the smallest available (free) label to an previously
// unlabeled slot.
void label(Problem& problem, size_t i) {
  if (i< problem.labels.size()) {
    if (NO_LABEL == problem.labels[i]) {
      problem.labels[i] = problem.freeLabels.top();
      problem.freeLabels.pop();
    }
  }
}

void unlabel(Problem& problem, size_t i) {
  if (i < problem.labels.size()) {
    if (NO_LABEL != problem.labels[i]) {
      problem.freeLabels.push(problem.labels[i]);
      problem.labels[i] = NO_LABEL;
    }
  }
}

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  Problem problem;
  createSampleProblem(problem);
  std::cout << problem << std::endl;
  std::cout << "acting the action...." << std::endl;
  unlabel(problem, 2);
  unlabel(problem, 3);
  label(problem, 0);
  std::cout << "after action:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << problem << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see, nice idea. The thing is that it's not about what is available or not but really according to the position after the move.